# Product of sequences convergence in $L^1$ and pointwise

Tags: measure-theory

Let $a_n(x)=f_n(x)\cdot g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is lebesgue integrable $\mathscr{L}^1(\lambda)$. Meaning

$$g(x)\quad \text{measurable and} \int |g|d\lambda < \infty$$

Suppose $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f=0$ but not $L^1$.

I am confused because in this question [Lebesgue integrable implies bounded a.e](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010247/lebesgue-integrable-implies-bounded-a-e) it seems this doesn't necessarily mean $g$ is bounded.

Does $\int |g|d\lambda < \infty $ imply $g$ is bounded?
If $g$ is bounded then $a_n$ converges point wise to  $0$ but not $L^1$ because $f_n$is not Cauchy.

Comment: If $\int |g| d\lambda < \infty$ then it does not imply that $g$ is bounded. A function whose graph consists of triangles with growing height and shrinking base (on the measure space $\mathbb R$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the Lebesgue measure) is the typical counterexample to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrable does not imply function-boundedness. Consider $(0,1]$ with the usual Lebesgue measure, then $\displaystyle\int_{(0,1]}\dfrac{1}{x^{1/2}}dx<\infty$ but apparently $1/x^{1/2}$ is not bounded on $(0,1]$.

Comment: If $f_{n}\rightarrow 0$ in $L^{\infty}$, then $\|f_{n}g\|_{L^{1}}\leq\|g\|_{L^{1}}\|f_{n}\|_{L^{\infty}}\rightarrow 0$, so $f_{n}g\rightarrow 0$ in $L^{1}$, but it is given that $f_{n}\rightarrow 0$ pointwise, not in $L^{\infty}$, it is hard to conclude anything.

Comment: The implication is not true unless in finite measure space. The functions $f_{n}=n^{-1}\chi_{[0,n]}$ converges to zero in $L^{\infty}$ but $\|f_{n}\|_{L^{1}}=1$.

Comment: $$\lim_n||a_n||_\infty=\lim_n\inf\{c\geq 0:\lambda\left(|a_n|\geq c\}\right)=0\}=\lim_n\inf\{c\geq 0:\lambda\left(\{|n^{-1}\chi_{[0,n]|}\geq c\}\right)=0\}=$$ how would you proceed

Comment: Perhaps the following way is easier: $|f_{n}(x)|=f_{n}(x)=n^{-1}\chi_{[0,n]}(x)\leq n^{-1}$, so $\|f_{n}\|_{L^{\infty}}\leq n^{-1}\rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1):

No, $\int |g| d\lambda < \infty$ does not imply that g is bounded. Notice that if we take $g\in \mathscr{L}^1(\lambda)((a,b))$, and an enumeration $(q_n)_n$ of the rational numbers in $(a,b)$, then by replacing the value of $g$ at $q_n$ with $n$ we obtain a new function $G$ which is equivalent to $g$ in $\mathscr{L}^1(\lambda)((a,b))$ (they agree almost everywhere in $(a,b)$) but $G$ is unbounded.